# Remove duplicates and extend a list?

Tags: python, list

im having some difficulties with a List im trying to fix and print.
So, im working with a friends API containing different toys. From this list i want to retrieve the name of the toy and the amount of sold toys for a specific date. So i created a new list to which i append all 'name' and 'amount of sold toys' to. However, since there are duplicate instances of specific toys with a specific 'amount of sold toys', ive written an if statement to only append the toys name if it isnt already in the list, and if it is already in the list, to extend the 'amount of sold toys'. The problem is, when i print the finished list, it will print out all the unique toys 'name' and 'the amount of sold toys', and no duplicates are printed, which is good. But, the 'amount of toys' is not extended. So even though i try to extend the list, neither 'name' or 'amount of toys' is extended. How do i fix this so that the 'amount of toys' is extended, but not the 'name' of the toy?

```
toy_list = []
for toy in toy_sales:
   try:
   toy_information = parse(toy(['toy_information'])
   if toy['name'] not in toy_list:
      toy_list.append(toy['name'])
      toy_list.append(toy['amount_of_toys'])
   else:
      toy_list.extend(toy['amount_of_toys'])
   

 new_list = []
 new_list.append(toy_list)

 print(new_list)
```

Is there something wrong with my code? I believe the if statement works in making sure there are no duplicate 'name' of the toys, but the extend seems unable to add the amount to the correct name, and therefore not adding it at all?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Thanks! An example of the toy data is a the name, which is a string, and the amount of toys, which is an integer: the output currently looks like this:

```
['Pokemon', 330000.0, 'Transformer', 45000.0]
```

this is if if i get only 2 items. currently im getting duplicate 'Transformer' if i dont use the 'not in' function, meaning there are 2 instances of 'Transformer': one with 45000 sales and aone with 50000 sales. Only the first shows up, which is 45000. If i use append instead of extend, the output looks like this:

```
['Pokemon', 330000.0, 'Transformer', 45000.0, 50000.0]
```

I thought the extend would give me:

```
['Pokemon', 330000.0, 'Transformer', 95000.0]
```

but it doesnt. It doesnt extend it, and if i append, it just adds them next to each other instead of the sum.

EDIT2: Hello, i attempted to do the same with a dict, but the output is empty.

```
toy_dict = {
       'name': 0
}

for toy in toy_sales:
   try:
   toy_information = parse(toy(['toy_information'])
   if toy['name'] not in toy_list:
      toy_dict['name'].append(toy['name'])
      toy_dict['amount_of_toys'].append(toy['amount_of_toys'])
   else:
      toy_dict['amount_of_toys'].update(toy['amount_of_toys'])

print(toy_dict)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the toy data, your expected output, and your current output. `list.extend()` is a *list* method which extends a list: `[1, 2, 3].extend([4, 5]) == [1, 2, 3] + [4, 5]`. It sounds like what you're trying to do is ADD numbers of toys?

Comment: I'm going to stop you right there. You need to edit your post to add the information I've requested, not put it in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, not too good at using stackoverflow. Edited my OP now!

Comment: Right, so you're attempting to use *list* methods to sum numbers... `list.append()` and `list.extend()` don't operate on numbers. To add numbers, you just do `a + b`. Unfortunately, the data structure you're using is going to land you in trouble, as you're just storing strings and numbers sort of willy-nilly, with no association between the strings and their corresponding numbers. Consider switching to a `dict`.

Comment: Thanks again! Im a bit ynfamiliar with dicts, how would i go about this? Would i declare a dict like i did a list above, and try to append the data the same way?

Comment: I edited my OP with an attempt at a dict, with no success :(

Comment: Again, you're missing the bigger point here: *you can't use `list.append()` OR `list.extend()` or `dict.update()` to ADD NUMBERS*. To add numbers, you use the addition operator, `+`. I suggest reading through a tutorial on lists and dictionaries because I think you're fundamentally misunderstanding how they work, and explaining those concepts is beyond the scope of this comment section and is also off-topic for Stack Overflow. I suggest looking at articles like [this](https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/) and [this.](https://realpython.com/python-dicts/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.
But I would recommend reading an article about python dics

```
toy_dict = {}

for toy in toy_sales:
   try:
       toy_information = parse(toy(['toy_information'])
       if toy['name'] in toy_dict:
           toy_dict[toy['name']] += toy['amount_of_toys']
       else:
           toy_dict[toy['name']]  = toy['amount_of_toys']

print(toy_dict)
```